# <image width> vs CSS width

Tags: html, css, image

Lets say I have a code like this:

```css
img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="blah.jpg" width="400">
```

And lets say the `blah.jpg` is `1000px` wide.
The HTML Code comes from 3rd party software, so I can not change it. (But I can select it with CSS).

I want to display the image as wide as it is declared in the img-tag, but I can not delete the CSS `width: auto`.

I can however overwrite this CSS Rule with whatever I want.

**EDIT** Is it somehow possible to display the the image with a width = width defined in image-tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> The HTML img-Tag is generated with 3rd party software
>
> Is it somehow possible to display the the image with a width = width defined in image-tag?

No it is not possible with CSS.

---

---

**OLD answer**

yes it is  using `max-width`

don't use `width` HTML tag, neither inline styles

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<img src="//lorempixel.com/1000/200">
```

> Sadly I don't know the width of the image in the CSS file. So I can
>   not set the width or max-width to 400

That's what classes and ID's are for (if you don't know how to use the new CSS 3 Selectors)

so apply for example a class and just set the `max-width` to that class, something like this:

```css
img {
  width: auto
}
.w400 {
  max-width: 400px
}
```

```html
<img class="w400" src="//lorempixel.com/1000/200">

<img src="//lorempixel.com/1000/200">
```

Comment: This is a superior solution to inline styles (though the latter would also solve the original posts issue).  I would go further and recommend the OP apply a class to the images they want to alter in this fashion, to offer further future-proofing should their needs change.

Comment: Sadly I don't know the width of the image in the CSS file. So I can not set the width or max-width to 400. If I could somehow delete the `width: auto` it would work.

Comment: @nbar sorry what? you don't know the width of the img in CSS? care to explain?

Comment: The HTML img-Tag is generated with 3rd party software. And the `width: auto` can not be removed. I can add aditional CSS Code but I do not know how big the images will be at that time.

Comment: but you want to have the image at 400px right?, see updated answer

Comment: I want the image at whatever the img-tag-widths value is. The only information how wide the image is is in the HTML img-tag.

Comment: why the downvote? It isn't my fault that OP only explains itself clearly in comments

Comment: @nbar you really shoud've explained all of this firstly in your question

Comment: if img is already with width=400px, why you want to have width:400px in CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with CSS. I certainly can't think of any way to do it.

You could create a very simple piece of javascript to generate inline styles for any img with a defined `width` attribute:

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[width]');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  var widthAttr = imgs[i].getAttribute('width');
  imgs[i].style.width = widthAttr + 'px';
}
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width="200">

<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width="300">
```

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I will do a JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps add another style class and use it for this image whatever height and width values you want to specify. That way, you get to keep the existing style information intact and have cleaner html.